# What is the state of opinion on Gilbert and Sullivan Operas

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to post a question about the plot of Iolanthe, but noticed there were no tags about the duo.

**Is this the right Stack to ask this question on?**

Comment: (If not, there's [very soon going to be a new Stack](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature?referrer=pG-ejQRSCH0RMbN3ps5MrA2) where G&S questions would definitely be on-topic.)

Comment: I’d make a tag for [tag:iolanthe], but no [tag:gilbert-and-sullivan], in accordance with our general author tag policy. I could see someone lobbying for an exception based on Gilbert and Sullivan being much better-known than their individual operas, though.

Comment: @Adamant I would vote for a G&S tag, since there won't be enough questions about any one operetta

Answer (score 13):

### The usual rules apply

- If the opera is science fiction or fantasy, then it’s on-topic.
- If it’s not really science fiction or fantasy, but has some elements of such, then questions *about those elements* are on-topic.

Let’s see how these apply to *Iolanthe*:

- Fairies [feature prominently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iolanthe) in the plot:

  > Twenty-five years before the beginning of the opera, the fairy
  >   Iolanthe committed the capital crime (under fairy law) of marrying a
  >   mortal human. The Queen of the fairies commuted Iolanthe’s sentence of
  >   death to banishment for life on the condition that Iolanthe left her
  >   husband and never communicated with him again. After the passage of 25
  >   years, the fairies, still missing Iolanthe deeply, plead with their
  >   Queen to pardon Iolanthe and to restore her place in fairyland
  >   (“Tripping hither, tripping thither”).
- There are [spells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iolanthe):

  > Offended, the Fairy Queen pronounces a magical “sentence” upon the
  >   peers: Strephon shall not only become a Member of Parliament, but will
  >   have the power to pass any bill he proposes (“With Strephon for your
  >   foe, no doubt”).

**So Iolanthe is on-topic.**

However, this would *not* be true of all Gilbert and Sullivan operas. Most of them, such as *Yeomen of the Guard* and *The Pirates of Penzance*, are simply not SF.

Comment: The Sorcerer and Ruddigore would also be OK, as they both have elements of the supernatural.

Comment: The non-fantasy operas _might_ be on topic on the new [Literature SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature?referrer=Eeunkl12fU5D4yRnMOivZg2), going into private beta tomorrow. Since it's still in private beta, we're still determining scope... come and try it!

Answer (score 6):

I've never seen Iolanthe, but [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iolanthe) (emphasis mine):

> In the opera, the **fairy** Iolanthe has been banished from **fairyland** because she married a mortal; this is forbidden by **fairy** law. Her son, Strephon, is an Arcadian shepherd who wants to marry Phyllis, a Ward of Chancery. All the members of the House of Peers also want to marry Phyllis. When Phyllis sees Strephon hugging a young woman (not knowing that it is his mother – **immortal fairies** all appear young), she assumes the worst and sets off a climactic confrontation between the peers and the **fairies**.

Seems perfectly on-topic to me.

I don't think I'd go so far as to say that Gilbert and Sullivan are on-topic *in general*, but at least this play looks like perfectly fair game.

Comment: Next up on Meta: "Tooth Fairy", featuring The Rock.